# What web apps can integrate other social networks/feeds into Facebook?

Tags: webapp-rec

I'm aware of [FriendFeed](http://friendfeed.com), which can integrate a number of sites and RSS feeds and pipe to my Facebook profile.  It works, but latency of updates can be pretty high (several hours).  Also, the Facebook post only indicates a FriendFeed icon but nothing about where the link came from.  To my friends, it's not clear it's a link to a site I Dugg or bookmarked in Delicious.  It looks like I had written it myself.

Facebook blog import is not exactly a good option; it only supports one RSS feed.

Are there other options for link sharing from other sources?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a fan of [RSSGraffiti](http://apps.facebook.com/rssgraffiti). It is a very nice, reliable, and configurable RSS-to-Wall app.

Comment: I gave this one a try and it's exactly what I was looking for!  Thanks.